# Vue3js router link to hash with offset value based on header

Tags: javascript, scroll, hyperlink, router, vuejs3

I have the following situation, I want to create router links with hashes in my navigation menu that lead to a certain section of the page, but with the offset of the header height for example 300px. Everything is working except for the header top property it kind of gets ignored. **The hash link goes to the desired position on the page but not the desired 300px offest from header. Even though I have the top property in styles set to -300px.** What am I doing wrong?

Example link in my Header component:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'Home', hash: '#desired-position' }">LINK</router-link>
```

Which leads to this section in Home component:

```
<section>
  <a class="anchor" id="desired-position"></a>
  <img src="../assets/pics/contact.webp" alt="contact" class="contact-img" />
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Header</h2>
     <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

I have styled the anchor like this:

```
 .anchor {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -300px; // Header Height
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

My scroll behavior in router index.js is as follows:

```
scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
if (to.hash) {
  const element = document.getElementById(to.hash.replace(/#/, ''))
  if (element && element.scrollIntoView) {
    element.scrollIntoView({ block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth' })
  }
  return { el: to.hash }
} else if (savedPosition) {
  return savedPosition
}
return { top: 0 }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by adding a top property along with el property in your router index.js file.
[Documentation](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html)

```js
scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
  if (savedPosition) {
    return savedPosition;
  }
  if (to.hash) {
    return { el: to.hash, top: 300 };
  }
  return { x: 0, y: 0 };
}
```